# How can create a proof that we have a sequence of binary digits?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Given a sequence of bits (either a 0 or 1), for example:

```
0110100110110001
```

How can one create a proof that we have this bit sequence, without actually revealing the bit sequence?

I know that there are several examples of proof mediums, such as polynomials for zk-SNARKs, however, how would one go about defining a proof medium for the above question?

**EDIT:** This bit sequence is derived from some input `x` which passes through some arithmetic circuit `C` in which a set of environmental conditions (i.e. delay) determine the propagation through paths, such that (for example) the first path to the goal will be associated with a 1, else 0, which ultimately make up a sequence of bits.

Comment: How is this bit sequence distinguished?  That is, you prove that you know a bit sequence that meets a specific property; what is that property?  Just proving that you know an arbitrary bit sequence is not interesting; it's trivial to pick a random one (and then you 'know' it).

Comment: @rshah, I wasn't able to see why a proof of knowledge doesnt fit to your problem?

Comment: @poncho I have given a brief example in the edited OP

Comment: @McFly I have an intuition it does, but how could one go from a sequence of bits to proving that we know (the knowledge component) it, without revealing it.

Comment: As an extension to poncho's comment: What ZK-Proofs do is they convince a verifier that some input is part of a formal language. They do so without e.g. revealing the witness for NP-languages and for most practical problems you have a language in NP and want to convince the verifier that you know the witness. The usual formalism would be to define a language $L$, a public input $x$ and some verification procedure $M$ s.t. $x\in L\iff \exists w: M(x,w)=1$ for the given bitstring $w$ you are trying to prove knowledge of.

Comment: So which one is private $x$ or $C$? the owners of $x$ and $C$ are different or is the same entity?

Comment: @A.Soleimani the private value here would be $w$ - the bitstring. We can say that $C$ is also private, however it could also be publicly known (however for keeping this simple, we will assume it is private). Also, the owner of $w$ and $C$ is the same entity

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're asking to prove that you have the result of running a secret input through a public process without revealing anything about this result.

For this proof to be an interesting one, you would have to output some value and then prove how it relates to the values you're hiding. If you don't do that, then you're simply proving that you ran any value through a public process. Since anybody can run values through a public process, this wouldn't be interesting. Does that make sense?

In other words, it's important that you figure out what is interesting about your proof. i.e. is there some fixed secret information you would need to have to prove what you're trying to prove?

If you reveal, say, the encryption $c$ of the bit string under a public key $pk$. Then proving that $c$ is the encryption under $pk$ of some bitstring $y$ seems like it could be interesting. You would probably also have to prove that $pk$ was generated honestly. Assuming unique decryption, this combination of proofs will fix the witness $(x,sk)$ which leads to the output $(c,pk)$.

This proof can be framed as an NP language where the value $(c,pk)$ has witness $(x,sk)$. You can then use standard zero-knowledge.